# How to display 2 50% sized form element using bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

By default bootstrap form elements take 100% width if class = 'form-control' is specified.

I have one `<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2"/>`. I want to display a select box and text box horizontally (inline) with a label at the top .Each component should take only 50% width. Additionally I am trying to put a panel inside

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
```

Try the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/haribalaji/apd1sucL/4/

Partial code available below.

```
<form>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="incidence">Incidence</label>
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-body">
                <div>
                    <select style="margin-top:0px;" class="form-control half-width-form-control" id="incidenceOperator" name="incidenceOperator">
                    <option value="0" disabled="">Choose Operator</option><option value="1">&lt;</option>
                    <option value="2">≤</option><option selected="" value="3">=</option>
                    <option value="4">≥</option>
                    <option value="5">&gt;</option></select><div class="input">
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="incidence" class="form-control half-width-form-control pull-right">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I dont want the `<select>` box inside `<col-md-1>` and textbox inside another `<col-md-1>`.

The fiddle displays selectbox and textbox one below the other. However they should appear inline or adjacent. How do we achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changed your code as

```
<form>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="autoSuggest">Term</label>
            <div class="react-autosuggest__container">
                <input type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="react-whatever-1" aria-expanded="false" class="react-autosuggest__input" placeholder="Type an ADR Term"></div>
                <div class="status"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="incidence">Incidence</label>
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-body">
                    <select  class="form-control half-width-form-control" id="incidenceOperator" name="incidenceOperator">
                    <option value="0" disabled="">Choose Operator</option><option value="1">&lt;</option>
                    <option value="2">≤</option><option selected="" value="3">=</option>
                    <option value="4">≥</option>
                    <option value="5">&gt;</option></select> 
                 <input type="text" name="incidence" class="form-control half-width-form-control pull-right">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div></form>
```

and css

```
.half-width-form-control {
           display: inline-block;
           width: calc(50% - 2px);
            float: left;
           box-sizing: border-box;
           margin-top: 5px;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome, Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Try this
https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/apd1sucL/10/

Basically, you want your panel's children to be inline, not the select.

```
#yourDiv > * {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  /*min-width: 200px;*/ /* this is to make it more responsive. If screen is smaller than 400px, they go back to being vertically aligned */
}
#yourDiv select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

And up to you if you want to use the min-width or not. I'd suggest you do, or add responsive CSS instead.